# Finding a special matrix for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose the linear transformation $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ with the following conditions:

$\dim(f(\mathbb{R}^n))=k$

$k<\min{(m,n)}$

Show that there is a base like $\mathfrak{B}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a base like $\mathfrak{B}^\prime$ for $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that:

$M^{\mathfrak{B}}_{\mathfrak{B}^\prime}(f)=\begin{bmatrix}
I_k & O\\O&O
\end{bmatrix}$

I tried to find $\ker(f)$ dimension $n-k$, But I can't find the proper base. I think i should use $\ker(f)$ elements but I have no idea how to do that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you very much, I just wrote my working and efforts for solving this question, but unfortunately they were useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to find $\ker(f)$ dimension $n-k$, But I can't find the proper base. I think i should use $\ker(f)$ elements but I have no idea how to do that?

Since there is no specific transformation given, you won't be able to actually *give* specific elements of the bases, but you can describe how you would be able to do this - in general.

As you said, the dimension of the kernel is $n-k$. Since the kernel is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$, you can find a basis of this kernel and it will consist of $n-k$ elements: $\left\{b_{k+1},\ldots,b_{n-1},b_n\right\}$.

You can then expand this to a complete basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$ by adding $k$ vectors, making sure all vectors are linearly independent, ending up with a basis $\mathfrak{B}$ of the form $\left\{\color{green}{b_1,\ldots,b_k},b_{k+1},\ldots,b_n\right\}$.

Recall that the $i$th column in the matrix representation $M^{\mathfrak{B}}_{\mathfrak{B}^\prime}(f)$ are the coordinates of the $i$th basis vector of $\mathfrak{B}$ (with respect to the basis $\mathfrak{B'}$).

Can you see how this choice of $\mathfrak{B}$, regardless of which basis $\mathfrak{B'}$ for $\mathbb{R^m}$ you pick, already realizes 'half' of the demanded form of the matrix, namely the parts in blue:

$$M^{\mathfrak{B}}_{\mathfrak{B}^\prime}(f)=\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{I_k}  & \color{blue}{O}\\ \color{red}{O} & \color{blue}{O}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Maybe you can take it from there?

**Hint**: use the images of the basis vectors of $\mathfrak{B}$ to construct a basis $\mathfrak{B'}$ that realizes the parts in red above.

Comment: Thanks, I think $b_1,\dots,b_k$ are in $\mathfrak{B^\prime}$ but how about other elements of $\mathfrak{B^\prime}$?

Comment: No, those are in $\mathfrak{B}$ (and are elements of $\mathbb{R^n}$!), but as I said: consider $f(b_1)$, $f(b_2)$ ... Those are elements of $\mathbb{R^m}$.

Comment: So if $f(b_1)=b^\prime_1,\dots,f(b_k)=b^\prime_k$ then $b^\prime_1,\dots,b^\prime_k$ are in $\mathfrak{B^\prime}$ but $f(b_{k+1}),\dots,f(b_n)$ can't be represented by $\mathfrak{B^\prime}$ elements?

Comment: Correct: so you get the first $k$ elements of $\mathfrak{B^\prime}$ by taking the images of the first $k$ elements of $\mathfrak{B}$ and you (*arbitrarily*!) expand this to a complete basis of $\mathfrak{B^\prime}$ for $\mathbb{R^m}$ by adding $m-k$ linearly independent vectors.